# Parsing S Expression

Tags: haskell, s-expression

Given the following definitions that make up an **S Expression** from Prof. Yorgey's [course](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/11-applicative2.pdf):

`data Atom = N Integer | I Ident deriving Show`

and

`data SExpr = A Atom | Comb [SExpr]` 
deriving Show

What should the full data type be (in Haskell) for the following?

*(bar (foo) 3 5 874)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it would be something like

```
Comb
    [ A (I "bar")
    , Comb
        [ A (I "foo")
        ]
    , A (N 3)
    , A (N 5)
    , A (N 874)
    ]
```

Whenever you encounter an open parenthesis you would start a new `Comb` expression, so `(foo)` is `Comb [A (I "foo")]` while `foo` is simply `A (I "foo")`.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume the Ident type is a String.

- *bar* as an Atom is `I "bar"`, and as an SExpr is `A (I "bar")`
- ditto for *foo*
- *(foo)* is an SExpr and is constructed as `Comb [ A (I "foo") ]`
- *3* as an Atom is `N 3` and as an SExpr is `A (N 3)`
- ditto for *5* and *874*
- the complete construction of *(bar (foo) 3 5 874)* (which is an SExpr) is

.

```
Comb [ A (I "bar")
     , Comb [ A (I "foo") ]
     , A (N 3)
     , A (N 5)
     , A (N 874)
     ]
```