# Writing Parser for S Expressions

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to write a Parser for [S Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894888/parsing-s-expression) from Prof. Yorgey's [2013 homework](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/11-applicative2.pdf).

`newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }`

Given the following definitions, presented in the homework:

```
type Ident = String

-- An "atom" is either an integer value or an identifier.
data Atom = N Integer | I Ident
  deriving Show

-- An S-expression is either an atom, or a list of S-expressions.
data SExpr = A Atom
           | Comb [SExpr]
  deriving Show
```

I wrote a parser for `Parser Atom` and `Parser SExpr` for `A Atom`.

```
parseAtom :: Parser Atom
parseAtom = alt n i
   where n = (\_ z -> N z) <$> spaces <*> posInt
         i = (\ _ z -> I z) <$> spaces <*> ident

parseAAtom :: Parser SExpr
parseAAtom = fmap (\x -> A x) parseAtom
```

Then, I attempted to write a parser to handle a `Parser SExpr` for the `Comb ...` case:

```
parseComb :: Parser SExpr
parseComb = (\_ _ x _ _ _ -> x) <$> (zeroOrMore spaces) <*> (char '(') <*> 
                                     (alt parseAAtom parseComb) <*> (zeroOrMore spaces) 
                                        <*> (char ')') <*> (zeroOrMore spaces)
```

Assuming that `parseComb` was right, I could simply make usage of `oneOrMore` for `Parser [SExpr]`.

```
parseCombElements :: Parser [SExpr]
parseCombElements = oneOrMore parseComb
```

So, my two last functions compile, but running `runParser parseComb "( foo )"` never terminates.

What's wrong with my `parseComb` definition? Please don't give me the whole answer, but rather a hint - for my own learning.

Comment: asking a question and not wanting it's answer is quite dumb, if you don't want to see the answer just don't look at it, I have the same problem and stuck thanks to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am very suspicious of `zeroOrMore spaces`, because `spaces` is usually a parser which *itself* parses zero or more spaces.  Which means that it can parse *the empty string* if there aren't any spaces at that point. In particular, the `spaces` parser *always succeeds*.

But when you apply `zeroOrMore` to a parser that always succeeds, the combined parser will never stop - because `zeroOrMore` only stops trying again once its parser argument fails.

As an aside, `Applicative` expressions like `(\_ _ x _ _ _ -> x) <$> ... <*> ... <*> ......` which only use a single of the subparsers can usually be written more succinctly with the `*>` and `<*` combinators:

```
... *> ... *> x_parser_here <* ... <* ...
```